# Why res.render() doesn't send local variables to the client without template engine?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I need to access the variable `user` in my client-side that sent by

```
res.render('home.html', { user: req.user });
```

without using template engines like `pug` or `ejs`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not a templating language, so it can't be used to send variables.

`res.render()` function compiles your template , inserts locals there, and creates html output out of those two things. The syntax is as follows -

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
```

The *view* argument is a string that is the file path of the view file to render. For this to work, you need a template or view engine .

In html, you can't dynamically pass/insert data variables. That's the main use case for  templating engine. They put runtime/dynamic value in html which is what you are probably looking for.

In short, its better to use any template engine like pug,jade,ejs, etc most of which would have almost similar syntax with html to render dynamic html pages.  I don't think there's any method (atleast simple enough) to send variables dynamically from server to client in an html page. Using a template engine would be the best choice in your use case.

For eg. you are passing user from server side and most probably want the passed variable to be rendered on the client side. You can just install an view engine like ejs - `npm install ejs`, set your view engine in *app.js* - `app.use('view engine','ejs');` , and just add this line in the html page where you want to send the variable to client side like - `<p> <%= user %> </p>` and that's it. Keep your html file in view folder and this would do it.